# Mocha cannot find module 'factories' (and it's an npm module)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

In my test file:

```
const factory = require('factories');
```

I installed the node-factories package two ways:

```
npm install --save-dev node-factories
// npm test fails to find module
npm install --save node-factories
// npm test also fails to find the module
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/jkanschik/node-factories) for node-factories, it specifies to `require('factories')` in the sources...

But no matter what, I keep getting this stack trace for JUST this module (and my local modules are in scope after I installed the dependencies),

```
Error: Cannot find module 'factories'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sjcbsolo/Engineering/flex/io-server/src/encryption/decrypthandler.tests.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/sjcbsolo/Engineering/flex/io-server/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/sjcbsolo/Engineering/flex/io-server/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/sjcbsolo/Engineering/flex/io-server/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sjcbsolo/Engineering/flex/io-server/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:459:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Any thoughts out there from node sharks?

Comment: how about showing the directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-factories has an error in docs, it seems.

```
const factory = require('node-factories');
```

will yield the results you're looking for.

As a rule, what you require is what it looks like on the file system as the folder the module installs to in node_modules, which is also what it looks like when you do `npm install`.